# How can I view origin configuration for API gateway in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created an api gateway and enabled `cors` for one path. I set the domain host in the field `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and click save. It shows success. but after that how I can view the values I set on `cors` setting? When I click `enable CORS` menu again, it aways shows `*` as the value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field. I'd like to see whether my settings is saved in apigateway. How can I confirm that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS option will add `OPTIONS` method to your API. In its `Integration Response` you can find the CORS headers:

[image]